# Transcript from PY to JS

Tags: javascript, python

I'm looking for a way to transcript this python code to javascript.

```
import subprocess
import os

path_to_exe = r"exe path"
path_to_file = r"file path"

subprocess.call([path_to_exe, path_to_file])
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/child-processes/how-to-spawn-a-child-process/).

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const pathToExe = 'explorer.exe';
const pathToFile = 'C:\\dev';

exec(`${pathToExe} ${pathToFile}`);
```